# Full table scan when querying against an indexed column

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing

I created an index for one table, a simple index just like that:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TRANSACAO_NOVA_STATUS ON TRANSACAO_NOVA(STATUS) TABLESPACE COMVENIF;
```

This table has 1000K registers insinde and the status table just 5 or 6 possible values. After created the index i expected that the query bellow would have a better performance:

```
select * from transacao_nova tn where tn.status = 'XXX'
```

but, the explain plan still show me a full scan with 16.000 cost.

any help? i'm not a dba but i need to improve this performance.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In some cases, the optimizing engine will decide it's cheaper to just do a full table scan instead of trying to use an index. Not saying that's happening here, but it is one reason for this to occur.

Comment: do u want the first rows only, or do you need all rows?  did u build stats?  why don't you accept answers to questions?

Comment: What's the distribution of the data - what percentage of your rows have the singular status code of interest?  And what does Oracle think the distribution of the data is?

Comment: If you're selecting 1/6th of the table changes are as @MarcB says all you've done is slow it down. Especially since you're selectinng `*` rather than just the indexed columns. Add the hint `/* full(tn) */` to your select and see how long that takes.

Comment: Is NULL one of the possible values?

Answer (score 4):

If there are only 5 or 6 different status values and a million records the query optimizer may be deciding it is not worth using the index to do a range scan that would still return a substantial number of all the records in the table.

You might look into using an index-clustered table for this application.

Comment: Good point. I missed the part about 5-6 values. A bitmapped index may be a good option also.

Answer (score 1):

If data in the status column es *skewed* (not uniform: some values appear very often and others appear very rarely), you can accelerate queries for the rare values by refreshing statistics (and verifying that you are calculating a **histogram** for the status column. This will make Oracle use the index *in the cases in which it is more efficient*.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm#autoId12

Be aware that automatically determining if a column needs a histogram is not a good idea as it may lead to inconsistent behaviour. It is better to manually specify histograms when needed. Also, histograms affect every query that uses those columns, so they should be collected with care.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to generate new statistics on the table.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm

Comment: i ran staticts but the poor performance remain ... i gonna see the answers about index clustered and return soon. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is to assume that an index range scan will be better than a full scan because you only want some "small" fraction of the total rows in the table.  But if the rows you want are scattered throughout the table's storage extents, locating them by an index lookup can be slower than just scanning the entire table.  I can't say for sure that's the case in your situation, but it's a possibility.

For a more in-depth discussion of this topic I recommend [this paper](http://www.hotsos.com/e-library/abstract.php?id=5).